# LINQ and nested query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, subquery, sql-to-linq-conversion

I need your help, I'm newbie in ASPNET mvc and I have a big problem with LINQ comprehension :D
I need to do this simple query:

```sql
Select * from Scarico
where Scarico.CaricoId in
(Select Id from Carico where Carico.MattonieraId = ID) <-- ID is
```

I tried to do this method to retrive the Scarichi List:

```cs
private List<Scarico> GetScarichiList(Guid id)
{
    var listaCarichi = from Carico in _db.Carico
                        where Carico.MattonieraId.Equals(id)
                        select Carico.Id;

    var ScarichiList = (from Scarico in _db.Scarico
                            where listaCarichi.Contains(Scarico.Id)
                            select Scarico).ToList();

    return ScarichiList;
}
```

Second variable "ScarichiList" does not contain any value, actually it should contain 2 values...
Where am i wrong?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Autogenerated SQL:
Query 1 (listaCarichi):

```sql
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id] FROM [dbo].[Carico] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[MattonieraId] = @p__linq__0}
```

Query 2 (ScarichiList):

```sql
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id]      AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Stato]   AS [Stato],
    [Extent1].[DataReg] AS [DataReg],
    [Extent1].[UltAgg]  AS [UltAgg],
    ...
FROM [dbo].[Scarico] AS [Extent1]
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1] FROM [dbo].[Carico] AS [Extent2] WHERE ([Extent2].[MattonieraId] = @p__linq__0)
  AND ([Extent2].[Id] = [Extent1].[Id]) )
```

Comment: Looks good, except `Equals` which can be replaced with `==`. Can you post generated SQL?

Comment: Actually first query work well and generated SQL is the following: {SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Carico] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[MattonieraId] = @p__linq__0}

Edit: Generated SQL of second query is:

SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Stato] AS [Stato], 
[Extent1].[DataReg] AS [DataReg], 
[Extent1].[UltAgg] AS [UltAgg], 
...
FROM [dbo].[Scarico] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
 1 AS [C1]
 FROM [dbo].[Carico] AS [Extent2]
 WHERE ([Extent2].[MattonieraId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent2].[Id] = [Extent1].[Id])
)

Comment: EF6... move forward and upgrade to EF Core. Edit question and post SQL into it

Comment: Sorry but I think I don't understand your reply..
I've edited my post.
Regarding to EF Core update, currently, I cant..

Comment: So, what is the problem? EF generated correct SQL. Your function `GetScarichiList` should run only one second SQL.

Comment: the problem, as I said in the first post, is that the second query returns 0 record instead there are 2 rows..